# How to install the tikz rulercompass library on mikTeX and Windows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing

On the CTAN, there is a library called `rulercompass` allowing to make geometrical constructions called ruler and compass. This library can be found here: [CTAN rulercompass](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rulercompass).

I downloaded this package and got the file `rulercompass.zip` After unzip it, the folder contains several files:

- README
- rulercompass.dtx
- rulercompass.pdf
- rulercompass_doc.pdf
- rulercompass_doc.tex
- tikzlibraryrulercompass.code.tex

In my local texmf, I created the following tree:

```
Localtexmf -> tex -> generic -> pgf -> libraries -> tikzlibraryrulercompass.code.tex
```

I upgraded the MikTeX database with `MikTeX Settings (admin) -> refresh FNDB` and I updated the formats with `Update Formats`

But this document of the official documentation does not compile!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}

}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
stop jumping ,
constrain
]
\path (0 ,0) node [name=0, ruler
compass/point=red , label ={0}];
\path (0) ++(30:2) node [ ruler
compass/point=red , label={a }];
\path (0) ++(70:2.7) node [ ruler
compass/point=red , label={b }];
\ ruler {0}{.}
\ ruler {0}{a}
\compass{0}{.−1}
\point{r0b}{c0a}{1}
\compass{0}{a+1}
\point{r0a}{c0{a+1}}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I compiled `rulercompass.dtx` in command line, but I did not get `.sty` file and I do not know what to do with the files obtained!

- What have I forgotten?
- How do I install a Tikz library on mikTex and Windows ?
- How to install this rulercompass library in particular?

Comment: It's already in MikTeX as mentioned on CTAN, so install it as you would any other package, via the MikTeX Package Manager.

Answer (score 2):

This code is badly coded. `}` in preamble, parasitic space, and 0 in place of O.
The answer was given on [TeXnique.fr](http://texnique.fr/osqa/).
I replaced O by C not to confuse  with 0.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stop jumping,constrain]
\path(0,0) node[name=C,ruler compass/point=red,label={O}];
\path (C)++(30:2) node[ruler compass/point=red,label={a}];
\ruler{C}{a}
\compass{C}{a}
\compass{a}{C}
\point{cCa}{caC}{1}
\point{cCa}{caC}{2}
\ruler{b}{c}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]